# How to debug breakpoint in pycharm at the end of file without adding a dummy line?

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm, breakpoints

Normally, if I want to run a python file beginning-to-end in pycharm, but stop at the end so I can see all the variables etc., I add a line at the end of the file like

```py
justadummyvar = 3
```

And attach a breakpoint to it.

Is there a way to just tell pycharm to debug run the file and stop at the end before flushing memory so I can get the same effect without changing the file contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing I was looking for is to right click within the editor and select `Run File in Python Console`. From there, you can see variables stored in memory and issue new commands after the entire script runs.

You can re-run or run with debug with the buttons on the left of the little console window.